# How to change the font size of axes and line weight in boxplot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, boxplot, axes

How to change the font size of axes and line weight in `boxplot`? Does the `boxplot` return a handle similar to the `plot` function?

I have tried the following:

```
figure
[ax h1 h2] = boxplot(x,y1,x,y2)
set(ax,'FontSize',14)
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FontSize` property of axes and `LineWidth` property of `boxplot` to change font size of axes and line weights of box plot respectively.

An example:

```
load carsmall;
bh = boxplot(MPG);
set(gca,'FontSize',16);
set(bh,'LineWidth', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sardar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729441/2627163) is the quick and short way to do this. I'll add to it that if you want to change only the box you should write:

```
set(bh(5),'LineWidth',2);
```

However, it may have some limitations, so here is a more in-depth way to control your boxplot.

### Boxplot Line

[`boxplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot) in Matlab has a different behavior than other plots, as it creates a group of lines and not one graphic object with a handle. Hence, sometimes you can only manipulate its parts when you create it (e.g. set the [`'BoxStyle'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html#input_argument_d0e118849) and [`'Colors'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html#input_argument_d0e118918) properties).

If you want to change it after creation, or you want to control properties that are not defined in the function input you need to recall the handle to the boxplot group. This is done with:

```
bx = findobj('Tag','boxplot');
```

Now you can manipulate all kind of things, and specifically the `LineWidth` of the box. Here is what `bx` is consist of:

```
>> bx.Children

ans = 

  7x1 Line array:

  Line    (Outliers)
  Line    (Median)
  Line    (Box)
  Line    (Lower Adjacent Value)
  Line    (Upper Adjacent Value)
  Line    (Lower Whisker)
  Line    (Upper Whisker)
```

You can see the each part of the boxplot is a different graphic element (all of them of type 'Line').  If you want to change only the box's property, you would write:

```
set(bx.Children(3),'LineWidth',3)
```

or more generaly:

```
set(findobj(bx,'Tag','Box'),'LineWidth',3)
```

and if you have only one boxplot you could write:

```
set(findobj('Tag','Box'),'LineWidth',3)
```

without even defining `bx`.

This will result in (using `carsmall` sample data):

[image: only box line]

If you want to manipulate all the boxplot lines, you would write:

```
set(bx.Children,'LineWidth',3)
```

and get the following result:

[image: all boxplot lines]

You can see more examples for changing boxplot properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525547/how-can-i-change-plotstyle-property-of-a-given-boxplot-figure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399688/matlab-boxplot-properties).

### Axes font size

Changing the axes font size is much more simple, and can be done by setting it directly (if this is the active axes):

```
set(gca,'FontSize',14);
```